# How do I store images from an sql query under different variables if they all have the same id?

Tags: php, html, sql, web

My problem is that I'm developing a property website that stores multiple imaages of a property in a different table to the one that stores the information about the table. I use the property_id from the properties table as a foreign key in the images table. However I want to retrieve all these images and store them as different variables for use elsewhere where I display these images in a slider. The code I'm using to retrieve the images is:

```
$image_result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_images
    WHERE property_id ='$id' ");


while($row_i = mysqli_fetch_array($image_result))
    {   
        $image = $row_i['image'];
        $property_display = cl_image_tag($image, 
                    array( "width" => 800, "height" => 600, "crop" => "fill" ));

    }
```

I can't think of how to get separate variables for each of the different images, as they each have the same property id. Where I want to use these variables is here:

```
<img class="mySlides" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/drfkdkwno/image/upload/v1476532177/<HERE>" style="width:100%">
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: just use an array. `while(...) { $arr[] = cl_image_tag(...); }`. You do NOT want to create new variables in a loop. littering your script with new arbitrary+dynamic variables is never ever a good idea.

Comment: Have you thought about adding another column to your images table called id. This can be the unique ID for your image and you can still locate specific property images using the property_id column.

Comment: @Steve I do have this field in my table, but how can I use it to control the variables, i.e. if the image id is 1, how could I say, $property_image<image id here> = then the image name, and loop this for each of the reuslts in the query

Comment: Chat here if you want... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126765/question-40271153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126765/question-40271153)...

Expanding on your code, here's the PHP to get the data,

```
// prepare array to hold image data
$property_display = [];

// query
$image_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE property_id ='$id' ");

// process results
while($row_i = mysqli_fetch_array($image_result)) {   
    // get the image name 
    $image_name = $row_i['image_name'];
    // note the [] here - adding a new element to the array
    $property_display[] = cl_image_tag($image_name, 
                array( "width" => 800, "height" => 600, "crop" => "fill" ));

}
```

and here's getting the data (also checking for no images)

```
if ($property_display) {
    // iterate over array
    foreach ($property_display as $image) {
        // echo the image tag stored in the array
        echo $image;
    }
} else {
    echo 'No property images!';
}
```

Quite basic but should hopefully give you what you need.

On a side note have a look at PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - this should really be the way you interact with your database. Especially to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: so the second edit works, but the format of the first one before the edit is what I was looking for? But I can't seem to get that code working

Comment: I merged the two edits and got my solution thanks for the help

Comment: Cool, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The `tbl_images` table requires a primary key. Use a surrogate primary key if you don't have anything else (it's what's mostly used anyway). In other words - an image ID, that's auto-increment or something. Identify the image by that surrogate key.

You could also use the row number, but that's very unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];  and use is WHERE property_id =  '$id';
```

And after:

```
<img src = "<?php $row_I['image'];? >" width="" height="" />
```